# Angular, CloudFront, OAI - top level objects in bucket returned, but not objects with paths

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CloudFront distribution with the following Origin:

`my-bucket.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

*Note: I have tried using the "static web hosting format" that includes `.s3-website` as opposed to `.s3` when I had static web hosting enabled on the bucket, but that simply results in a 403 all the time.*

*Also note: I left the Origin Path empty because when I set it as `/index.html`, it results in 403s.*

And it has OAI permissions on the bucket. I have verified that the bucket policy is correct:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXX"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The CloudFront distribution has the following Error Pages:

```
HTTP error code | Minimum TTL (seconds) | Response page path | HTTP response code
403               10                      /index.html          200
404               10                      /index.html          200
```

The bucket contains the dist output of an Angular app with all the scripts, styles, favicon, manifest, etc. at the top level and icons under the path `/assets/icons/icon-XXxXX.png`. As it stands, with (most of) the app components being returned properly, I do not have static web hosting enabled.

Everything works like a charm except that, despite all the scripts, styles, favicon, and webmanifest being returned when requested by the app, requests for icons do not return the png icon, but instead return this response:

```
Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.
```

Which tells me that requests to `app.com/assets/icons/icon-XXxXX.png` result in a 403 and are caught by the distribution's 403 error handler, simply returning `index.html`, despite the components of the app at the top level of the bucket being returned properly.

I have exhausted google and every tweak I attempt ends up resulting on 403s all around.

Can anybody help me figure out why just the assets are failing to return properly?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was Chrome caching the response for that asset from a previous version of my distribution when it was not returning correctly. Disabling cache fixed the issue. Maybe this will help somebody else having the same headache.